# How can I hyphenate elements of this concatenated string only when the next element is not null?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a concatenated string.

```
 contract_id || coalesce(line_of_business, '') || coalesce(group_year::TEXT,'')
```

Contract_id always exists. There other two elements can be null. When all three elements are present, the string output looks like this:

```
contractIDLOB1
```

For readability, I want to place a hyphen between each string if the next string is not null. For example: `contractID-LOB-1` but never `contractID-LOB-`. Is there a way to do this in Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a case expression, instead of a `coalesce()` to get more fine-grained with your logic:

```
contract_id 
   || CASE WHEN line_of_business IS NOT NULL THEN '-' || line_of_business ELSE '' END 
   || CASE WHEN group_year IS NOT NULL THEN '-' || group_year::TEXT ELSE '' END
```

Many RDBMS's rewrite, behind the scenes, COALESCE() into a case expression anyway, so this shouldn't be any more expensive to run.